# How can I call the values from my xml file to my as3 code

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I cant get the values from my xml file

XML file (db.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<character>
    <main hp="100" lvl="10" dmg="5" def="5" exp="0.00" gold="10"/>
</character>
```

My AS3 Code

```js
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("db.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void {
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myXML);
}

var mylvl:Number = myXML.main.@lvl;
var myhp:Number = myXML.main.@hp;
var mydmg:Number = myXML.main.@dmg;
var mydef:Number = myXML.main.@def;
var myexp:Number = myXML.main.@exp;
var mygold:Number = myXML.main.@gold;

lvlDis.text = String(mylvl);
hpDis.text = String(myhp);
dmgDis.text = String(mydmg);
defDis.text = String(mydef);
expDis.text = String(myexp);
goldDis.text = String(mygold);
```

There's no error on the Compile tab but the values wont display

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until your loader complete loading the xml file and then you can use its data, so you can do like this :

```
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    myLoader.load(new URLRequest('db.xml'));
    myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void
{   
    setTexts(new XML(e.target.data));   
}

function setTexts(xml:XML):void
{       
    lvlDis.text = String(xml.main.@lvl);
    hpDis.text = String(xml.main.@hp);
    dmgDis.text = String(xml.main.@dmg);
    defDis.text = String(xml.main.@def);
    expDis.text = String(xml.main.@exp);
    goldDis.text = String(xml.main.@gold);  
}
```

Hope that can help.